# Proof: For each $a$, the function $\gamma_a$ is a permutation of the set $G$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

For $a\in G$ we can define a function $\gamma_a:G\to G$ given by $\gamma_a(x)=axa^{−1}$ for $x\in G$.

Then for each $a$, the function $\gamma_a$ is a permutation of the set $G$.

**Proof:**
By definition, a permutation of a set, say $X$, is a bijective function from $X$ to itself.

So, since $\gamma_a$ is defined from to $G$ to $G$ we only have to show that it is bijective.

*Surjection:* Let $y\in G$ and since the function maps elements in $G$ onto $G$ we have $axa^{−1}=y$. This implies $x=a^{−1}ya$.

So, we have $$\gamma_a(a^{−1}ya)=a(a^{−1}ya)a^{−1}=aa^{−1}yaa^{−1}=y.$$

*Injection:* For any $x,y\in G$ we have $$\gamma_a(x)=\gamma_a(y).$$ This implies $axa^{−1}=aya^{−1}$ and using the cancellation laws we get $x=y$.

Therefore, $\gamma_a$ is a bijective and so, a permutation of the set $G$.

My question is if my arguments above are correct. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: You might also observe that $\gamma_{a^{-1}}$ is the inverse map of $\gamma_a$, if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, but some of your wording is slightly odd and makes the argument harder to read than it should be (I don't know if you're a native English speaker, which might be the problem). For example:

> Injection: for any $x, y \in G$ we have…

This means "it is true that for any $x, y \in G$", when what you mean is the following:

> Injection: Suppose we had $x, y \in G$ with $\gamma_a(x) = \gamma_a(y)$…

Additionally:

> Surjection: Let $y \in G$ and since the function maps elements in $G$ onto $G$ we have $axa^{−1}=y$. This implies $x=a^{−1}ya$.

You mean something like "Let $y \in G$, and set $x = a^{-1} y a$. Then $\gamma_a(x) = \gamma_a(a^{-1} y a) = y$. Therefore, since $\gamma_a$ hits every $y \in G$, it is surjective." The way you've written it, you've basically assumed your conclusion in saying $axa^{-1} = y$.

(An instance which does not affect readability: you've missed out the word "function" in "Therefore, $\gamma_a$ is a bijective  and so, a permutation of the set $G$." Alternatively, you could use "$\gamma_a$ is a bijection".)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was wondering if you could point out other examples of odd wording I have used. I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: No problem. I've edited my post with the other example.